Fixed bug when embedding another site's API needed to scroll down to see all in WordPress LMS
Currently I am working with worldpress LMS.
I have embedded a third party Chess.com
Code snippet below.
<iframe id="12090081" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;border:none;" src="//www.chess.com/emboard?id=12090081"></iframe><script>window.addEventListener("message",e=>{e['data']&&"12090081"===e['data']['id']&&document.getElementById(`${e['data']['id']}`)&&(document.getElementById(`${e['data']['id']}`).style.height=`${e['data']['frameHeight']+30}px`)});</script>

But when I go to the website, it forces me to scroll down to see it all. Is there any way to fix it and not have to scroll down to see it?
bug photo
I wish I didn't have to scroll down to see it

Maybe adding height to the iframe is enough. iframe { height: 9999px; }. But it’s not clear from your code whether that would suffice.
